# E not loading texture

Tags: python

trying to code minecraft using ursina engine but e is not loading texture.

'int' object is not callable
File "C:\Users\selwy\Desktop\Coding Files\Python Files\Minecraft Ursina\mesh_terrain.py", line 17, in **init**
e.texture_scale*=64/e.texture.width()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\selwy\Desktop\Coding Files\Python Files\Minecraft Ursina\Main.py", line 11, in 
terrain = MeshTerrain()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

#mesh terrain

```
from random import randrange
from ursina import *

 class MeshTerrain:
    def __init__(this):
    
        this.block = load_model('block.obj')
        this.textureAtlas = 'texture_atlas_3.png'

        this.subsets = []
        this.numSubsets = 1
        this.subWidth = 32

        for i in range(0,this.numSubsets):
            e = Entity( model=Mesh(),
                        texture=this.textureAtlas)
            e.texture_scale*=64/e.texture.width()
            this.subsets.append(e)
    

    def genBlock(this,x,y,z):
    # Extend or add to the vertices of our model.
        model = this.subsets[0].model

        model.vertices.extend([ Vec3(x,y,z) + v for v in 
                            this.block.vertices])
    
        # This is the texture atlas co-ord for grass :)
        uu = 8
        uv = 7
        model.uvs.extend([Vec2(uu,uv) + u for u in this.block.uvs])


    def genTerrain(this):

        x = 0
        z = 0

        d = int(this.subWidth*0.5)

        for k in range(-d,d):
            for j in range(-d,d):

                y = randrange(-1,1)
                this.genBlock(x+k,y,z+j)

        this.subsets[0].model.generate()
```

#main

```
from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController
from mesh_terrain import MeshTerrain

app = Ursina()

window.color = color.rgb(200,0,255)
subject = FirstPersonController()
subject.gravity = 0.0

terrain = MeshTerrain()

def update():
    pass
    # updateTerrain()


terrain.genTerrain()

app.run()
```

Comment: The error message is pointing you to the correct location. Most likely `e.texture.width` is returning an `int` type and your subsequent call `()` is causing the int to be called as a function- which is disallowed. Try changing `e.texture.width()` to `e.texture.width`

Comment: Thank you son rob i was so confused with the bug for 3 days and you helped :)